# How to load default category value in custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to load default categories in WordPress custom post type.

here is my code to create custom post type in a function.php

```
function my_post_type_portfolio() {
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
                array(
                'label' => __('Portfolio'),
                'singular_label' => __('Porfolio Item', 'theme1592'),
                '_builtin' => false,
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                //'hierarchical' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'page',
                //'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/images/icon_portfolio.png',
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'portfolio-view',
                    'with_front' => FALSE,
                ),
                'supports' => array(
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'thumbnail',
                        'excerpt',
                        'custom-fields',
                        'comments')
                    )
                );
    register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', 'portfolio', array(
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'label' => 'Portfolio Categories', 
        'singular_name' => 'Category', 
        "rewrite" => true, 
        "query_var" => true
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use plugin like "Types". With it you can do anything as:

1. Create custom post type.
2. Create Custom fields.
3. Create custom taxonomy or usr current categories. and More.

   Or:

For current code in arguments you can add:

```
'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
```

Comment: Where is the I put this

'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),

Comment: can please update above code..where the please your code